# Which would be the best agile approach in order to manage a Process Department?

Tags: agile, process, tfs

I'm in charge of the "processes and training" department in my company. Our main activities are:

- Document and publish the process of the company as well as procedures and functions of each sector
- Develop and document efficiency metrics to measure the performance of certain sectors
- Provide training on demand on various issues, internally and for clients

What would be an appropriate *agile* way to manage the tasks of such department? How would such way be best implemented in TFS?

Comment: Hello and welcome to PMSE. You seem to be asking about an application of a specific tool. What I'd suggest is to take a step back and choose the right approach first. From what you say, a Kanban seems a better start to document existing process and then improve it. I've made an edit to your question to make it more general - you can revert that edit if you want. In the meantime, you may want to take a look at http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/12548/how-can-we-apply-agile-to-a-consulting-firm/12549#12549 , since it should apply to your department as well.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm ok with the edit. I'll also take a closer look to Kanban and see how it can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Kanban is suitable for ongoing work

Kanban is suitable for managing ongoing work that does not have a specific start and an end. Sounds like the work you described is of this nature.

[I understand that TFS has a Kanban template.](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/VisualStudio/Announcing-Kanban-for-Team-Foundation-Service) However, I have not used this even though I have used the TFS Agile/Scrum template.

Here are some of the key aspects of Kanban:

- Visualize the workflow: Everyone should be able to see what everyone else is working on.
- Set Work In Progress (WIP) limits: To minimize context switching.
- Learn and improve continuously: Monitor the flow and keep making small, continuous improvements.

One of the key monitoring techniques for Kanban is the [Cumulative Flow Diagram](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj838789.aspx). This will show you where the bottlenecks are and they can become targets for improvement.

You can also set up separate horizontal lanes ([swimlanes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bharry/customizable-kanban-swim-lanes)) for the three types of work that you described.